# Is it ok to call ServletRequest.getInputStream() multiple times in loop?

Tags: java, servlets

Encountered some code doing this inside a servlet:

```
while ((read = request.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1)
    buffer.write(bytes, 0, read);
```

While in most cases, `request.getInputStream()` is just returning a field somewhere, I was thinking there might be dynamic wrappers or such that could get into a bad state.

Is there anything written in the docs about doing such a thing that I can use as a case for pulling the `getInputStream()` code out of the loop?

Comment: Maybe there's no case according to the docs (see Karol's answer). But you could still make the case that code reviewers will keep stumbling upon this stone and spend resources unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to call `getInputStream()` multiple times, the Servlet Specification only prohibits using it together with `getReader()`. As per [the `ServletRequest#getInputStream()` method javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()):

> Retrieves the body of the request as binary data using a ServletInputStream. Either this method or getReader() may be called to read the body, not both.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a ServletInputStream object containing the body of the request
>
> **Throws:**
>
> - IllegalStateException - if the getReader() method has already been called for this request
> - IOException - if an input or output exception occurred

A particular Servlet implementation is free to return a wrapper object but at the end of the day one is supposed to always expect `ServletInputStream` can throw throw `IOException` at some point (e.g. connection reset).

If we take Apache Tomcat as an example, the HTTP connection handling logic is in [`AbstractProtocol.ConnectionHandler.process()` method](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/28d79f56c376a871c77397e1aa1b86aeb0366fdf/java/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProtocol.java) and is very defensive. The cleanup code for the HTTP connection and the underlying socket [runs after `catch(Throwable )`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/28d79f56c376a871c77397e1aa1b86aeb0366fdf/java/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProtocol.java#L981) so application error shouldn't interfere with resource cleanup.